# What kinds of corn can be nixtamalized?

Tags: corn, soaking

What kinds of corn are the standard for [nixtamalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixtamalization)? I mean, do they use sweet corn, popcorn, dent corn, flour corn, flint corn, pod corn, something else, or some/all of the above? I'm guessing it would work with any corn, but some might be ideal for the purpose. Maybe it depends on what you want to do with that nixtamalized corn. Let's assume it's for masa de maíz, for use with tortillas and stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it looks like I found my answer:

[Field corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_corn) is used for creating [masa de maíz (see this link for my source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masa). Field corn includes a few types of corn (dent, flour, flint, waxy). I'm not sure if all types of field corn are used for masa de maíz, however. So, if anyone has a more specific answer, feel free to give it.

I'm *guessing* really any kind of corn could be nixtamalized, however (but some kinds may be more ideal than others). Other kinds of grain besides corn can also be nixtamalized.

Comment: I just use corn from the feed store. It's probably Roundup ready, but it works fine. Various sources on the internet say something to the effect "Popcorn can be nixtamalized, but the results are poor because the skin is especially tough and the endosperm is small and hard." http://www.cookingissues.com/index.html%3Fp=5129.html The stuff is expensive anyway. Most decent Latino stores will carry dried purple sweet corn. It works nicely, but has a higher sugar content than field corn.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Thanks for the information! :) I'll edit that part out of my answer, about the sweet corn.